# using =if and Cell in the same formula?

Tags: excel, if-statement, cell

I hope someone can help me.
I am trying to use specific critirea to bring back cell information.

I have some raw data on Sheet 1, and on sheet 2 I have a list of references, I want to know if those references are in my raw data on sheet 1 and if so, tell me what cell it is in.

the formula I have tried is:

```
=IF(Sheet1!A:A=Sheet2!A1,Cell("row"),0)
```

This just brings back '0' all the time, even though I know the data is in sheet 1. 
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot compare a range to a single cell `Sheet1!A:A = Sheet2!A1` in Excel without array formulas.

Instead, use the [MATCH](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions03.html#MatchArg) function, which returns the position of a matching cell. In your case:

```
`=MATCH(Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!A:A,0)`
```

Answer (score 0):

If your search range extends in a single column (e.g.:[A1:A100]), then you could try the following, which will inform you: a) if your lookup value was not found, and b) if the value is found, it returns you in which row it was found **for the first time only**. That is, if the lookup value exists in more than one cells inside your search range, this function will return only the row of the first cell containing the value.

In this example, B1 is the lookup value, and A1:A10 the search range:

=IF(ISNA(MATCH(B1;A1:A10;0));"does not exist";CONCATENATE("found on row:";MATCH(B1;A1:A10;0)))